# Mysql- low level communication

Tags: mysql, cursor, protocols, connector

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/execute-packet.html

in this page i found that in MySQL 5.0.0 there is for types of cursor:

0: CURSOR_TYPE_NO_CURSOR
1: CURSOR_TYPE_READ_ONLY
2: CURSOR_TYPE_FOR_UPDATE
4: CURSOR_TYPE_SCROLLABLE

however i didn't found a method ( i mean in low level communication ) to send a query or command for skipping rows or backward in rows list if a cursor is defined.

this is for doing something like a mysql connector.

thanks in advance

Comment: I think that isnt possible. You buffer the query result and then you can move the cursor.

Comment: but can any one tell me what this CURSOR_TYPE_* are useful for ?